# tic tac toe game in JavaScript does not display that game is a draw

Tags: javascript

I have created a small game using JavaScript. The problem is that it does not display that the game is a draw.

I have tried a lot but as a beginner I don't understand it. The errors are commented in the code below

```js
let turn = "X"; 
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
let message = document.querySelector('#print');
let restart = document.querySelector('#but');
let steps = {
    X : [],
    O : []
}


const winConditions= [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],

    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],

    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6],
];


//console.log(winConditions);

cells.forEach ( cell => {
    cell.addEventListener ("click",() => move(cell) );
});
restart.addEventListener("click", restartGame);
//console.log(inputs);

function move(cell) {
    cell.value = turn; //marking cells with X or O depends on turn
    cell.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; //making cell not clickable
//taking index of the cell and push it to step tracker
    let cellIndex = parseInt ( cell.getAttribute("data-cell"));
    if ( turn === 'X') {
        steps.X.push(cellIndex);
    } else {
        steps.O.push(cellIndex);
    }

changeTurn();
}
//functon bellow does not display when game is Draw!!!
function changeTurn() {
    let winner = validateWin();

    if (winner) {
        stopGame(${winner}'s win!);
    } else if (!winner && steps.X.length + steps.O.lenght === 9 ){
        stopGame(Draw!);
    } else { 
        if(turn === 'X'){
            turn = 'O';
        } else {
            turn = 'X';
        }
        message.innerHTML = ${turn}'s turn;
    }    
}
//does not show when X is winner???
function validateWin () {

    let win = null; 
    let winner = null;
    if ( turn === 'X') {
        win = winConditions.some(winCondition => {
            return winCondition.every( condition => steps.X.includes(condition));
        });
        if (win) winner = 'X';
        
    } else if ( turn === 'O') {
        win = winConditions.some(winCondition => {
            return winCondition.every(condition => steps.O.includes(condition));
        });
        if (win) winner = 'O';
    }
    return winner;
    }


function stopGame(msg) {
    message.innerHTML = msg;
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    });
}

function restartGame() {
    steps.O = [];
    steps.X = [];
    turn = 'X';
    message.innerHTML = "X's turn";
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.value = null;
        cell.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: orangered;
  font-size: 45px;
}


/* 3*3 Grid */

#b1,
#b2,
#b3,
#b4,
#b5,
#b6,
#b7,
#b8,
#b9 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Reset Button */

#but {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 95px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Player turn space */

#print {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Main container */

#main {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Game Instruction Text */

#ins {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1 class="playerText">TIC TAC TOE</h1>

  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="0" type="text" id="b1" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="1" type="text" id="b2" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="2" type="text" id="b3" readonly>
  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="3" type="text" id="b4" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="4" type="text" id="b5" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="5" type="text" id="b6" readonly>
  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="6" type="text" id="b7" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="7" type="text" id="b8" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="8" type="text" id="b9" readonly>
  <br><br><br>
  <button id="but">
            RESET
        </button>

  <br><br>
  <p id="print"> X's Turn </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it if the syntax and spelling errors are fixed?

Comment: i don't get it. what do you mean

Comment: Also string delimiters around `stopGame(${winner}'s win!);` and         `message.innerHTML = ${turn}'s turn;`

Comment: can you rewrite my code please

Comment: Just add the backticks where you need them: `stopGame(\`${winner} wins!\`);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. spelling mistake - 2nd length in `if (!winner && steps.X.length + steps.O.length === 9) {`
2. Missing backtics

I shortened some of the code too.

Here is the fixed code

```js
let turn = "X";
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
let message = document.querySelector('#print');
let restart = document.querySelector('#but');
let steps = {
  X: [],
  O: []
}


const winConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],

  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],

  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];


//console.log(winConditions);

cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener("click", () => move(cell));
});
restart.addEventListener("click", restartGame);
//console.log(inputs);

function move(cell) {
  cell.value = turn; //marking cells with X or O depends on turn
  cell.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; //making cell not clickable
  //taking index of the cell and push it to step tracker
  let cellIndex = parseInt(cell.getAttribute("data-cell"));
  steps[turn].push(cellIndex);
  changeTurn();
}
//functon bellow does not display when game is Draw!!!
function changeTurn() {
  let winner = validateWin();
  if (winner) {
    stopGame(`${winner} wins!`);
  } else if (!winner && steps.X.length + steps.O.length === 9) {
    stopGame("Draw!");
  } else {
    turn = turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
    message.innerHTML = `${turn}'s turn`;
  }
}

function validateWin() {
  return winConditions
    .some(winCondition =>  winCondition
      .every(condition => steps[turn].includes(condition))) ?  turn : null;
}


function stopGame(msg) {
  message.innerHTML = msg;
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  });
}

function restartGame() {
  steps.O = [];
  steps.X = [];
  turn = 'X';
  message.innerHTML = "X's turn";
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.value = null;
    cell.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: orangered;
  font-size: 45px;
}


/* 3*3 Grid */

#b1,
#b2,
#b3,
#b4,
#b5,
#b6,
#b7,
#b8,
#b9 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Reset Button */

#but {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 95px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Player turn space */

#print {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Main container */

#main {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Game Instruction Text */

#ins {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1 class="playerText">TIC TAC TOE</h1>

  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="0" type="text" id="b1" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="1" type="text" id="b2" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="2" type="text" id="b3" readonly>
  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="3" type="text" id="b4" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="4" type="text" id="b5" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="5" type="text" id="b6" readonly>
  <br><br>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="6" type="text" id="b7" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="7" type="text" id="b8" readonly>
  <input class="cell" data-cell="8" type="text" id="b9" readonly>
  <br><br><br>
  <button id="but">
            RESET
        </button>

  <br><br>
  <p id="print"> X's Turn </p>
</div>
```